# SVN: How to export changed files with all the log messages to a list?

Tags: svn, file, tortoisesvn, export

Is it possible to export all changed files between two revisions, with the history to a list/file..?

lets say I made several changes to some files.
What i would like to have is some sort list like this:

```
rev |  filename  | log
----+------------+-----------------
20  | test.cs    | added ftr 21
20  | file.cs    | added ftr 21
21  | test.cs    | removed bug 212
22  | awesome.cs | added ftr 23
22  | test.cs    | added ftr23
...
```

I could not find some sort of option to do this in TortoiseSVN. But i would think this is not that dificult to retrieve..?
Anyway, if someone can help me with this...

Thanks in advance!

Bruno

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using TortoiseSVN, so this is very easy using Show Log.

Simply use the TortoiseSVN show log command. Then, in the window appearing, select the range of revisions you want to have info on, clicking on the first and shift+clicking on the last. Then just copy with Ctrl-C and then paste the results in your favorite text editor. The output will show the revision number, author, date, commit message and list the modified, added and deleted files.

Answer (score 7):

you might try the command line version in cygwin:

```
 svn log -v -r revFrom:revTo
```

The -v option gets you the list of files that were modified added.  Adding --xml outputs the information as XML and you might be able to transform it into what you ultimately need.

Answer (score 3):

svn log [repo_url] -v -r revFrom:revTo

e.g. 
svn log http://svn.mozilla.org/projects/ -v -r 113000:113800